# Creating a Date is adding automatically one hour to my input date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

let's say I have this date as input :

```
var _dateA = 2018-11-15T11:13:26.687Z
```

If I'm doing, whatever,

```
var _dateB = new Date(_date)
```

or

```
var _dateB = moment(_date)
```

I get this as result ==>

```
_dateB = Thu Nov 15 2018 12:13:26 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
```

I understood that there's timezone trouble, but how can I get a Date object or Moment object, without having this one hour more?

Wanted result => `Thu Nov 15 2018 11:13:26 GMT+0100`

Current result => `Thu Nov 15 2018 12:13:26 GMT+0100`

Comment: You don't have "this one hour more". It is just a different representation than you expect. But that is how it is designed to work. Are you looking for [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)?

Comment: You're in the GMT+0100 time zone, but your input is UTC (zulu time zone)

Comment: There is no issue, you have just missed the change of timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Date.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) that converts date to string, using the UTC time zone

```js
var _dateA = '2018-11-15T11:13:26.687Z';
var _dateB = new Date(_dateA);
console.log(_dateB.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "output" a `Date` object via `console.log()`, `alert()`, etc the `toString()` method is used by default, converting the date object to a local timezone string for display (which is why you are seeing your date in your local time).

Parsing date strings with the `Date` constructor is not recommended (although, I suspect that most browsers probably handle ISO 8601 dates, like the one in your question, fairly well) - [see the dateString parameter note here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters). So, if you need to construct a date object as well as output a date string, then you could parse the ISO 8601 string with `split()` using a regex character set for multiple delimiters, then construct a UTC date object with `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`. You could also do this with moment.js but the below should illustrate what is happening in a bit more detail.

For example:

```js
const text = '2018-11-15T11:13:26.687Z'
const [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, ms] = text.split(/[-T:.Z]/);
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d, hh, mm, ss, ms));
console.log(date.toLocaleString()); // date string in local timezone
console.log(date.toUTCString()); // UTC date string
console.log(JSON.stringify(date)); // ISO 8601 date string in most browsers
```

Comment: And if I want to do a diff() with the UTC date and now() ? How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @Mayoul if you use `date` from the snippet above and do something like `let diff = new Date() - date`, then `diff` will be the difference in milliseconds between the current datetime and `2018-11-15T11:13:26.687Z`